# php require with backslash error

Tags: php, require

I'm using namespace and trying to auto load requires. On __auto_load function the var class_name comes with backslash. And this throws:

`Warning: require(controller\Example\Test.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...`

But if I try require `controller/Example/Test.php;` its works.

I tried run the same thing on the other sever and its works. Then I thinks that is problem of configuration or PHP version.

I now that it can be resolved by replacing backslash by slash, but I want to know why this happens.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of the autoload() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a backslash is different than a forward slash. Backslashes are often times for escaping characters. Windows uses backslashes for directory structures, but most Unix-based operating systems will use normal slashes.

---

If you run:

```
root@PC:~$ cd \
>
```

Linux will think you are trying to escape the enter/newline and allow you to keep entering your command. This is different if you use a forward slash, where it will take you to the root directory:

```
root@PC:~$ cd /
root@PC:/$
```

---

You can always use PHP's constant [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) with something like:

```
$path = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('controller', 'Example', 'Test.php');
require($path);
```

Source: [Anonymous](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php#113343)